# FROM statment could not be found where is expected

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following query

```
SELECT ut1.*, 
IF NULL(ut2.status, 0) status 
FROM user_permissions ut1 
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT * FROM user_permission_data WHERE user_id = 1) 
 ut2 ON ut1.id = ut2.options_id
```

Once I run query I get error like

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I try to move `FROM` keyword after `ut2` but still have problem.Where I made mistake ? What is wrong with this query ? Why I get this kind of error ?

Comment: replace IF NULL with COALESCE

Comment: I think the problem is when you use IF FULL...

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL - only in PL/SQL

Comment: You can replace COALESCE like suggested before or NVL function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NVL(x1, x2)` to coalesce null value.

```
SELECT 
  ut1.*, 
  NVL(ut2.status, 0) status 
FROM user_permissions ut1 
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT * FROM user_permission_data WHERE user_id = 1) 
 ut2 ON ut1.id = ut2.options_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is unnecessary.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT up.*, COALESCE(UPD.status, 0) status 
FROM user_permissions up LEFT JOIN  
     user_permission_data upd
     ON up.id = upd.options_id AND upd.user_id = 1 ;
```

I also strongly recommend that you use meaningful table aliases (abbreviations for the table names) rather than arbitrary, meaningless aliases.